# Codeigniter + SSL + .htaccess + infinite redirects

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl

I am trying to setup SSL on my codeigniter site, but I'm running into a few problems.

Codeigniter refuses to access https://. Firefox displays this error:

> The page isn't redirecting properly.
>   Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

My config file has this as the base_url

```
$config['base_url'] = "http".((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "s" : "")."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

My .htaccess file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|first_cut|media|robots\.txt|user_guide|xd_receiver\.htm|channel.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Ideally I would like https:// to always be applied to these folders...

- /facebook/competition
- /dimensions/

... and then optional https for the rest of the site

Any ideas?

Comment: what redirections do you get? run `curl -i $url` and show us the output.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly try this code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://www.projectname.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.projectname.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#search folder and redirect to subdomain 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} dimentions
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.projectname.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you only want to redirect files that do not exist to `index.php`. There's an easier way for that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This comes back with 500 Internal Error and would that solve the SSL issue anyway?